# Cannot connect to setup database on heroku with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Not sure what I am doing wrong, I tried just leaving out the production section in my database.yml but that didn't work, now I have this:

```
development:
  ...

test:
  ...

production:
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
```

My gemfile:

```
gem 'pg', :group => :production
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5', :group => [:development, :test]
```

I am getting this error when running:

```
Running rake db:setup on ⬢ still-crag-69600... up, run.8579 (Free)
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "test"]
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:246:in `resolve_symbol_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:227:in `resolve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:141:in `resolve'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:139:in `create_current'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this under production:

```
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Ensure that you have created a [postgresql addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql). `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is set automatically when you add a heroku postgresql addon.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_name
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
```